# How to understand the structure of taxonomy in drupal 6

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, taxonomy

I mean everywhere in code example on internet it's littered with tid, vid etc.
I want to understand how it is related to taxonomy. Can someone give me some references?
Actually I need to create nodes along with hierarchical terms they would be in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First...

- tid = Term ID
- vid = Vocabulary ID

Chapter 14 in [Pro Drupal Development](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430209895) provides a good overview of developing with Drupal's taxonomy system.

This [Programatically adding taxonomy term to node](http://groups.drupal.org/node/89744) thread from groups.drupal.org may give you a jump start.